# Vue Router - Not all params are being passed

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have this component that is being ca;;ed by the Vue Router. But not all the params are being received by the component. The link is working because the browser URL is being created correctly e.g. `http://localhost:8080/dashboard/brands/1/car/1`. But the `brandId` doesn't get received by the component. It stays 0.

This is my link that redirects to the component:

```
      router-link
        tag="button"
        :to="{ name: 'CarDetail', params: { brandId: brandId, id: car.id } }"
      >
        Link
      </router-link>
```

Here is the path defined in the router class:

```
const parseProps = r => ({ id: parseInt(r.params.id) });

  {
    path: "/dashboard/brands/:brandId/car/:id",
    name: "CarDetail",
    props: parseProps,
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "brands" */ "@/views/CarDetail.vue")
  }
```

This is the component:

```
export default {
  name: "CarDetail",
  data() {
    return {
      car: {}
    };
  },
  props: {
    id: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    brandId: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does parseProps look?

Comment: I have updated the code. This is just a function to make sure the id's are of type Number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `brandId` in `parseProps` :

```
const parseProps = r => ({ id: parseInt(r.params.id),brandId: parseInt(r.params.brandId)  });
```

Comment: Thank you this solved it. But isn't there a more elegant way of parsing all props?

Comment: Try out `props: true,` instead of `props: parseProps,`

Comment: @Stephen does `props: true,` solve your problem?

Comment: It does not sole it.  But Original answer does.